# Adding External jar's in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a program to connect to MySQL. I add Connector/j using eclipse add external jar option. Program works fine in eclipse. But when I created the executable jar using eclipse and when i run it, it always give ClassNotFoundException. Please tell me how to add external jars to my jar. Or is there any other error? Please can anyone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to export your project as a 'Runnable Jar file' (Right-click on project->Export...->Runnable Jar file) that will place all dependencies in one jar file.

Otherwise you will need to include a classpath to the additional jars either in the manifest.mf file or on the command line with the -cp option.

```
java -cp .;myjar.jar;mysql.jar my.package.classname
```

Comment: You cannot use the -cp option with an executable jar. The java -jar option will ignore other command-line parameters.

Comment: I tried the first option and its not working. Eclipse is automatically generate the file classpath. I checked it and it has paths to external jars. But still not working.

Comment: sorry yeah you will need to add the jar itself to the classpath and specify the main class to run

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA - In the wizard are you specifying the correct project in the 'Launch Configuration' and selecting 'Extract required libraries into generated JAR'?

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA - From the 'Export->Java/Runnable Jar file' wizard

Comment: Well I am very new to java and eclipse. Please can you explain me with more details.

Comment: @scott Yes I did it. And still no use.

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA - On the left-side you can right-click on your project folder then in the middle of menu is an 'Export...' option. On the dialog popup type 'Runnable' into the filter and select 'Runnable Jar file'

Comment: @scott yes I have created a runnable jar. But still has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a jar that includes the files from all the dependent jars.  The classloader won't be able to find the classes if you simply include the jar files themselves inside the executable jar.  There is an eclipse plugin called FatJar that does this.

http://fjep.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the class-path element to your jar MANIFEST and list your external jar inside the MANIFEST

like this:

```
Manifest-version:1.0
Class-Path: class0.jar
class1.jar
class2.jar
class3.jar
class4.jar
...
```

One jar per line.

Comment: Please can you explain how to do that. I am new to java.

Comment: i have edited my response.  Look for a folder META-INF. inside you will find the manifest.mf.  copy and paste my example and replace classx.jar with your .jar.

Comment: No, you can just put the relative path to it ex: lib/yourjar.jar