# Could not able to add External Jar in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

[while I was adding external jar but it is deactivated so that I couldn't able to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixAL9.png)

Comment: you can able to add the Jars . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126178/adding-external-jars-in-eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse: in the Libraries tab all buttons are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491394/eclipse-in-the-libraries-tab-all-buttons-are-disabled)

Answer (score -2):

Please try to add jar in Deployment Assembly